# Form validation issue PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to create a form, which will check if the input is empty or not. If it is empty there should be a text like "Required field". There is a notice saying, that `surName` has an undefined index.

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
  $name_error="";
  $sname_error="";
  $f_name="";
  $s_name="";

  if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
    if ($_POST['firstName']!=='') {
      $f_name=$_POST['firstName'];
    }
    else {
      $name_error="Required Field *";
    }
  }
  if ($_POST['surName']!=='') {
    $s_name=$_POST['surName'];
  }
  else {
    $sname_error="Please fill this out";
  }
?>


 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Registration form</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="head">
       <p>Registration Form</p>
     </div>
     <form action="Register/final.php" method="POST">
       <label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
       <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $f_name; ?>"><br><br>           
       <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $name_error; ?></p>
       <label for="surName">Last Name</label><br>
       <input type="text" name="surName" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?   
         php echo $s_name;?>"><br><br>
       <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $sname_error;?></p>
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why not use HTML5's `required` attribute for a start? `<input type="text" name="foobar" required>` will mark the fields as such. KISS...

Comment: There's one place where you have `<?` and `php` split onto separate lines. That won't work in PHP. Is that error in your original code, or did it happen when you posted it here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have a submit button. Another thing is that you didn't use your `if` statement of `$_POST['surName']` after submit. You can use it like this :

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);

$name_error = "";
$sname_error = "";
$f_name = "";
$s_name = "";

    if (isset($_POST['submit_button']))
    {
        if ($_POST['firstName'] != '')
        {
            $f_name = $_POST['firstName'];
        }
        else
        {
            $name_error = "Required Field *";
        }

        if ($_POST['surName'] != '')
        {
            $s_name = $_POST['surName'];
        }
        else
        {
            $sname_error = "Please fill this out";
        }
    }

?>



 <html>
    <head>
       <title>Registration form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div class="head">
            <p>Registration Form</p>
       </div>

       <form action="Register/final.php" method="POST">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $f_name; ?>"><br><br>           
            <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $name_error; ?></p>
            <label for="surName">Last Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="surName" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $s_name;?>"><br><br>
            <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $sname_error;?></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Register">
      </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

well for starters, you could use the built-in HTML5 input validator `required`

```
<input type="text" required>
```

This will provide that nice user message on submit asking them to please fill out that field.

Secondly, you can check on the server using `empty` instead of `if ($_POST['surName']!=='')`

```
if ( !empty($_POST['surName']) ) {
   // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Note that the server side validation should be used no matter what. The HTML5 validation is a nicety for your users but the server validation should be mandatory for the security of the application.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is basically there already...

1. I guess the `}` bracket for `if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {` should be just before `?>`
2. There is missing something like `<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Register">`
3. And considering what *Jeff Puckett II* says

So, if I do the changes 1 and 2 to your code, it might look like this:

```
<?php
  $name_error="";
  $sname_error="";
  $f_name="";
  $s_name="";

  if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
    if ($_POST['firstName']!=='') {
      $f_name = $_POST['firstName'];
    } else {
      $name_error="Required Field *";
    }

    if ($_POST['surName']!=='') {
      $s_name = $_POST['surName'];
    } else {
      $sname_error="Please fill this out";
    }
  }
  ?>



 <html>
      <head>
       <title>Registration form</title>
      </head>
      <body>
       <div class="head">
        <p>Registration Form</p>
       </div>
       <form action="Register/final.php" method="POST">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $f_name; ?>"><br><br>           
        <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $name_error; ?></p>
        <label for="surName">Last Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="surName" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $s_name;?>"><br><br>
        <p style="color: red;"><?php echo $sname_error;?></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send">
      </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you've put the surName validation outsite of submit conditional;
          `

```
         if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
              if ($_POST['firstName']!=='') {
                  $f_name=$_POST['firstName'];
                 }else{
                    $name_error="Required Field *";
                  }
                 if ($_POST['surName']!=='') {
                   $s_name=$_POST['surName'];
                  }
                else{
                  $sname_error="Please fill this out";
                 }
               }

     ?>`
```

Your can improve this a little bit by using an associative array like this     `errors = array();` and then `$errors['surName'] = "this is field is required"`;